# Mexican FMM -- the flight number and airline name. But a ticket is adviced to be bought afterwards

Tags: mexico, entry-permit, fmm-tourist-card

The Mexican electronic permission FMM for 180 days must be obtained priour to buying a ticket to Mexico. However, it now has the fields "flight number" and "airline name" as required ones.

I don't have a ticket yet and I read recommendations that for Mexico I must frist apply for FMM and then, after I've gotten it, buy a ticket. And I did this last time. The last time there were no "flight number" and "airline name"

How can I get it then? What to fill out the fields with?

[image]

Comment: Where have you read that you need to complete the FMM form before you buy a ticket? What citizenship do you hold?

Comment: I have never heard of having to get FMM _before_ buying a ticket.  Can you post links to where you were told this?

Comment: @ZachLipton, russian

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to get an FMM before booking tickets. If you're flying, you don't need to visit that web site at all.

The current procedure is that you will be given the FMM form during the flight to fill out before landing in Mexico. You will pay the fee to the airline as part of your ticket price (IATA code UK on your ticket receipt). You show the FMM at immigration when you enter Mexico, then keep it and turn it in when you check in for your flight departing Mexico.

You can also purchase the FMM in advance from the gob.mx web site, as you have discovered. In this case you will have already paid for it. The web site will give you the FMM that you must print, show to immigration, and turn in when you leave Mexico. If you're flying you shouldn't do this, since you have already paid the FMM fee via the airline. Buying the FMM in advance is advisable when you enter Mexico by road, as you may find it difficult to get it at some border crossings.

(Mexican citizens and residents are not supposed to be charged the FMM fee (IATA code UK) or the departure tax (IATA code XD). If you are a Mexican citizen or resident and were charged this, [your airline can issue a refund](https://travelwithgrant.boardingarea.com/2017/09/21/how-to-request-mexico-tourism-tax-refunds-for-mexican-citizens-residents-transiting-visitors-tonei/).)

Comment: Generally the FMM fee is included in the airline ticket price, so you don't have to pay anything at the airport.

Comment: @krubo Interesting. I just looked at an upcoming flight to Acapulco and sure enough United charged for it.

Comment: @cihun If you are absolutely certain that your airline did not charge you for the FMM then you can buy your own. But double check your booking first.

Comment: You can fill out the FMM form online for free if you're arriving by air. It just gives you a copy to print out. The website won't charge you. But you can also fill out the paper form on board the flight instead. It made no difference at all on my last trip, though they're supposedly rolling out electronic kiosks at some airports that could change things.

Comment: I have cleaned out a series of comments that did not add knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

If you are from Russia or another [country from which Mexico requires visa for tourists (Spanish)](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/), and you don't meet one of the exceptions, then you'll need a visa or SAE before you travel to Mexico as a tourist.  See the link above to see if you qualify for an exception, for example, if you have a valid US or Schengen visa.  Citizens of Russia, Turkey or Ukraine can get an SAE online instead of getting a visa.

This is not the same as an FMM.  You still get the FMM on the plane or when you arrive in Mexico.  (Citizens of other countries who don't need a visa will also get the FMM on the plane or when they arrive, and the FMM fee is usually included in the airfare.)  But you need the visa or SAE before you travel.

Here is the Mexican embassy in Russia's [website about how to get SAE (Russian)](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/rusia/index.php/ru/visas/2-uncategorized/183-autorizacion-visa-rus) [(Spanish)](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/rusia/index.php/es/visas/2-uncategorized/124-autorizacion-electronica).  It also confirms that you will complete the FMM when you arrive in Mexico.

Comment: wait, my question wasn't  what   FMM is and how to apply for it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question? I think you asked how to get FMM before you buy your tickets. But that indicates a misunderstanding, because you can't get FMM before you buy your tickets. If you travel by air, you will get FMM on the plane or when it arrives. What you may need before you buy your tickets is SAE.